# Rails Validations :format getting skipped on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Rails is skipping the :format validation on create. On create, it's accepting anything at all. Then on update :presence and :format are both working as expected. How can I alter this so it'll :allow_blank on create and check the format too?

```
validates :mail, :allow_blank => true, :on => :create,
                 :format => { :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z]{2,})$/i },
                 :length => { :maximum => 60 },
                 :presence => true, :on => :update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using separate `validates` statements for :create, :update, and all life cycle events. Your `:on => :update` option is essentially overwriting the `:on => :create` option when you lump them all together.

```
validates :mail, :format => { :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z]{2,})$/i },
                 :length => { :maximum => 60 }

validates :mail, :allow_blank => true, :on => :create,

validates :mail, :presence => true, :on => :update
```

Comment: Not sure why but I got: "you need to supply at least one validation" if I had :allow_blank on its own. So I put it with the :format/:length group and had :presence separate as you suggested and everything is working now.